# Flutter/I want to rewrite the http.post method to retrofit+dio, but I'm getting DioErrorType.other

Tags: flutter, api, http, retrofit, dio

I want to rewrite the Post method of the API from the http method to retrofit + dio, but I'm getting a type error. Please tell me how to solve this problem. http method is working fine.

Error: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic＞', but got one of type '_JsonMap'.

Here is the reference of the API.
https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/documents/analyzeEntities

```
//this is model class
@freezed
abstract class TextEntity with _$TextEntity {
  const factory TextEntity({
    required String name,
    required String type,
  }) = _TextEntity;
  factory TextEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$TextEntityFromJson(json);
}

//this is http(working fine)
class CloudNaturalLanguageAPI {
  final _client = http.Client();

  Future<List<TextEntity>> getTextEntities(String body) async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:analyzeEntities?key=$key',
      );
      final response = await _client.post(url, body: body);
      final responseJson = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;
      final List<TextEntity> entities = [];
      for (final Map e in responseJson['entities']) {
        final entitiy =
            TextEntity(name: e['name'].toString(), type: e['type'].toString());
        entities.add(entitiy);
      }
      return entities;
    } finally {
      _client.close();
    }
  }
}

//this is retrofit + dio
@RestApi(baseUrl: 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2')
abstract class TextEntityDataSource {
  factory TextEntityDataSource() =>
      _TextEntityDataSource(Dio());
  @POST('/documents:analyzeEntities?key=$key')
  Future<List<TextEntity>> getTextEntities(@Body() String body);
}

//this is body
final String body = json.encode(
       {
         'document': {
           'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
           'content': 'this is test text.',
         },
         'encodingType': 'NONE'
       },
     );
```

[http responseJson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8L87.png)

[generated file (It seems to be stuck at final _result.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOBs.png)

[error point (External file browser_adapter.dart)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdCFQ.png)

full error log.

```
Restarted application in 168ms.
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 84:3        castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 452:10  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 635:14     as_C
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 847:31                                            assureResponse
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 615:14                                            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 57:12                                         complete
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 540:44                                             onValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 602:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15               <fn>
Source stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                    get current
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 473:35                                                fetch
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                    runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                    _async
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 472:31                                                fetch
packages/ichibun_write/data/remote_data_sources/text_entity_data_source.g.dart 26:32  getTextEntities
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                    runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                    _async
packages/ichibun_write/data/remote_data_sources/text_entity_data_source.g.dart 21:43  getTextEntities
packages/ichibun_write/data/repositories/text_entity_repository.dart 33:10            get
packages/ichibun_write/controllers/text_entity_list_controller.dart 16:35             get
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                    runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                    _async
packages/ichibun_write/controllers/text_entity_list_controller.dart 13:13             get
packages/ichibun_write/ui/widgets/cnl_test_widget.dart 17:55                          <fn>
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 989:21                                    [_handleTap]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 198:24                                  invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 608:48                                         handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 296:5                                          [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 230:7                                          handlePrimaryPointer
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 563:9                                   handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 94:12                               [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 139:9                               <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13              forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 137:17                              [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 123:7                               route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 439:19                                     handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 419:14                                     dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 322:11                                    dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 374:7                                      [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 338:5                                      handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 296:7                                      [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 279:32                                     [_handlePointerDataPacket]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1020:13                                   invoke1
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 184:5                                     invokeOnPointerDataPacket
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 130:39                                        [_onPointerData]
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 558:18                                        <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 511:21                                        <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 217:16                                        loggedHandler
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
at http://localhost:65180/packages/dio/src/interceptors/log.dart.lib.js:1004:21
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:40066:59)
    at _FutureListener.catchError.handleError (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:34994:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35567:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35593:17)
    at _Future.new.[_complete] (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35429:25)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.complete (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:34896:31)
    at onValue (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:34658:49)
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:40062:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:34983:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35551:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35589:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35437:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35458:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:65180/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

Comment: try print `responseJson['entities']` in log. What you get?

Comment: @JohnJoe Thank you for your comment. [{name: test text, type: WORK_OF_ART, metadata: {}, salience: 1, mentions: [{text: {content: test text, beginOffset: -1}, type: COMMON}]}]

Comment: check the log. Did it point to which line?

Comment: @JohnJoe Is the log what you see in the left window when you set a debug point? I will attach a picture to the question.

Comment: @JohnJoe I Created a print under the final responseJson and Placed debug points in print.

Comment: can you post full error which show in the console? Did the error point to which line?

Comment: @JohnJoe I added to the question.